# How can I activate an animation after a button press

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I would like to make it so on my website, when you click an image, an animation begins that shows an important message. If you click on the exclamation mark, it opens an important message. I want it to move from the exclamation point to the center and get bigger. This may not make 100% sense but I hope it does.  I will be around to answer questions. Note: all words in all caps are information that has been taken off to protect privacy. Also, some images are downloaded and cannot be dislayed, therefor please just click on where it says view important message! Thank you all so much! I would like to do this in pure JS, CSS, and HTML.

```js
function showImportantMessage() {
  var x = document.getElementById("importantMessage");
  var y = document.getElementById("importantButton");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:white;
  
}
.center{
  text-align: center;
  
}
.w3-theme {
background-color: #477d72;
}
.w3-theme-text {
background-color: #549688;
}
div.a {
  text-indent: 50px;
}
div.b {
  font-size: 60px;
}
button {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
}
button:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
  
  //font-weight: 800;
  background-color: blue;
  //color: crimson;
}
.margin {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.buttonSelector {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  
}

.home {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.imgOfNAME {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 45px;
}
.importantMessage {
  width: 700px;
}
.importantPic {
  
}
.point {
  float: right;
}

.w3-theme {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
.w3-themeTwo {color:#000 !important; background-color:#c2c2c2 !important}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="faviconStepTWO.png"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      
      <div class="buttonSelector">
  <button class="w3-bar-item home" onClick="BacktoHome()">Home</button>
  
  
  
  <!---<button class="w3-bar-item" onClick="OpenParents()"> Parents </button>--->



      </header>
      </div>
      
      <div class="margin">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
  <h1 class='center'>TITLE</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img class="imgOfNAME point" id="importantButton" onclick="showImportantMessage()" width="70px" src="exclamtionMarkONE.png" title="View important message">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<center>
<div id="importantMessage" class="importantMessage">
  <div class="w3-border">
    <br>
    <img width="70px" class="importantPic" src="pointONE.png">
    
   
  <h3><b>Important message!</b></h3>
  <p>DATE</p>
  <p>Dear NAME,
<br>
<br>
INFO
<br>
<button class="w3-button  w3-themeTwo w3-round w3-hover w3-hover-theme w3-hover-theme" id="importantButton" onclick="showImportantMessage()" style="width: 115px; height: 50px;">OK, got it.</button>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</center>
  <script>


  var 
x = document.getElementById("importantMessage");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}</script>


  </body>
  </div>
</html>
```

es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate elements by adding classes that have "transform" CSS rules. Check out this example https://jsfiddle.net/alvinmoyo/08Lt2ekw/15/ in which you can scale an element. Read further on the css animation property

```
.div{
     animation: all ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: I see I wasnt 100% perfect when explaining my question. I would like to make the actual message to be animated not the image, although this is extremly helpful.

Comment: I also forgot to mention I am using keyframes for my animation. Would that change any of the code?

Comment: I got it, the image animation is just an example, use the same principle to animate your message. Check out the animate.css library to save your time on creating animation classes. Just add the animate.css classes to your message using js in a similar manner.

Comment: No the Keyframes won't change anything on JS only just toggle the class which references the keyframes Animation

Comment: Only one more question. If I am using animate.css how do I make the animation only play after the button? Do I add the class somewhere?

Comment: const element = document.querySelector('.my-element');
element.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__bounceOutLeft');

Comment: use this function,the speed  and callback parameters are optinal. function animateCSS(element, animationName,speed, callback) {
    let node = element;

    node.classList.add('animated', animationName, speed);

    function handleAnimationEnd() {
        node.classList.remove('animated', animationName);
        node.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);

        if (typeof callback === 'function') callback()
    }

    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);



}